# Insert data into specific column of table in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How to insert input data into specific column.

For example I have column clinicName and clinicArea in Table clinic. I make a form for insert and save clinicName only (model2). When I try register the form, it save info into table person for (model) but model2 not save to table clinic. But when I include model2 clinicArea form, the data can save. I just want insert the clinicName only. Below is the code:

form.php

```
<div class="person-form">

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'personName')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'personNumber')->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($model2, 'clinicName')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

controller.php

```
 public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Person();
    $model2 = new Clinic();
    
    if ($this->request->isPost) {
        if ($model->load($this->request->post()) && $model2->load($this->request->post())) {
            $model->save();
            $model2->personId = $model->personId;
            
            $model2->save();
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'personId' => $model->personId]);
        }
    } else {
        $model->loadDefaultValues();
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'model2' => $model2,
    ]);
}
```

clinic model

```
   public static function tableName()
{
    return 'clinic';
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['clinicName', 'clinicArea', 'personId'], 'required'],
        [['personId'], 'integer'],
        [['clinicName', 'clinicArea'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['personId'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Person::class, 'targetAttribute' => ['personId' => 'personId']],
    ];
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'cliniId' => 'Clini ID',
        'clinicName' => 'Clinic Name',
        'clinicArea' => 'Clinic Area',
        'personId' => 'Person ID',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the Clinic Model check the rule, you had set :
['clinicName', 'clinicArea', 'personId'] as required and if you do not pass it model cannot be saved, see Docs [yii2 validation rules](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-core-validators#required):

```
requiredValue: the desired value that the input should be. If not set, it means the input should not be empty.
```

You will have two ways:

1. remove clinicArea from required (but only if is not an important column)
2. add clinicArea in the form
3. on save pass false param (validation controll will not start)

you said that clinicArea id not important for you so delete it from required rule.

Tips: check in DB if you setted it as Not Null, you will have error if you try to save model with clinicArea = null

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have a question on [highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77239291/6854117) can you please check it out?

Answer (score 0):

You had set  ['clinicName', 'clinicArea', 'personId'] as required so when model try to save data then this validation execute and model can not set data.

if you want to save data forcefully then you need to put like this :

$model2->save(false);

But this is not correct way.

Second way is to create scenario for single field set as required and used.

Comment: I have a question on [highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77239291/6854117) can you please check it out?